# C# Method to copy email using MailKit

Tags: c#, mailkit

in this method i try copy email from sourceClient to destinationClient, i what to copy all messeges in INBOX folder to INBOX folder. But have a issue and I don't now how to rerwite this code.

```
var sourceInbox = sourceClient.Inbox;
    await sourceInbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    var destinationInbox = destinationClient.Inbox;
    await destinationInbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    Console.WriteLine("Znaleziono folder INBOX na serwerze źródłowym.");
    Console.WriteLine("Znaleziono folder INBOX na serwerze docelowym.");

    // przesyłamy tylko wiadomości z folderu INBOX z sourceServer do destinationServer
    // jeśli chcemy przesłać wszystkie wiadomości, to należy zakomentować poniższe dwie linie
    //var uids = sourceInbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, null).UniqueIds;
    //uids = sourceInbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, null).UniqueIds;


    var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchOptions.All, null);

    foreach (var uid in uids.UniqueIds)
    {
        var sourceMessage = await sourceInbox.GetMessageAsync(uid);
        await destinationInbox.AppendAsync(sourceMessage);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Skopiowano wiadomości z folderu INBOX.");

    await sourceClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
    await destinationClient.DisconnectAsync(true);


    Console.WriteLine("Skopiowano wiadomości z folderu INBOX.");

    await sourceClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
    await destinationClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

meesege:

```
Exception occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentNullException
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in 
System.Private.CoreLib.dll but not handled in user code: 'Value cannot be null.'
at MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapFolder.<SearchAsync>d__304.MoveNext()
in Program.<CopyEmails>d__10.MoveNext() in 
line 61 - var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchOptions.All, null);

        foreach (var uid in uids.UniqueIds)
        {
            var sourceMessage = await sourceInbox.GetMessageAsync(uid);
            await destinationInbox.AppendAsync(sourceMessage);
        }
line 97
```

anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The following line is where the ArgumentNullException is happening:

```
var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchOptions.All, null);
```

...and the problem is that you are passing `null` (hence the ArgumentNullException).

I would recommend that you use the following line of code instead:

```
var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.All);
```

If you really want to continue using the SearchAsync method that takes a SearchOptions argument, then you should use this line of code instead:

```
var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchOptions.All, SearchQuery.All);
```

...but I doubt that's what you want, because that version of SearchAsync returns SearchResults instead of UniqueIds. Yes, the SearchResults *also* contains UniqueIds, but it does way more work and is not necessarily supported by all IMAP servers.

```
var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.All);
```

This code snippet is supported by *ALL* IMAP servers and will do the minimum amount of work needed for what you are doing.

Once you do that, all you'll need to do is modify this line:

```
foreach (var uid in uids.UniqueIds)
```

to this:

```
foreach (var uid in uids)
```

**Update for clarification:**

In the end, your code will look like this:

```
var sourceInbox = sourceClient.Inbox;
await sourceInbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

var destinationInbox = destinationClient.Inbox;
await destinationInbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

Console.WriteLine("Znaleziono folder INBOX na serwerze źródłowym.");
Console.WriteLine("Znaleziono folder INBOX na serwerze docelowym.");

// przesyłamy tylko wiadomości z folderu INBOX z sourceServer do destinationServer
// jeśli chcemy przesłać wszystkie wiadomości, to należy zakomentować poniższe dwie linie
//var uids = sourceInbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, null).UniqueIds;
//uids = sourceInbox.Search(SearchOptions.All, null).UniqueIds;


var uids = await sourceInbox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.All);

foreach (var uid in uids)
{
    var sourceMessage = await sourceInbox.GetMessageAsync(uid);
    await destinationInbox.AppendAsync(sourceMessage);
}

Console.WriteLine("Skopiowano wiadomości z folderu INBOX.");

await sourceClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
await destinationClient.DisconnectAsync(true);


Console.WriteLine("Skopiowano wiadomości z folderu INBOX.");

await sourceClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
await destinationClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
```

**Update 2 (Copying messages while preserving delivery date):**

```
var summaries = await sourceInbox.FetchAsync(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate | MessageSummaryItems.Flags);

foreach (var summary in summaries)
{
    var sourceMessage = await sourceInbox.GetMessageAsync(summary.UniqueId);

    var request = new AppendRequest(message, summary.Flags.Value, summary.Keywords, summary.InternalDate.Value);

    await destinationInbox.AppendAsync(request);
}
```

Comment: thank you but.
foreach cannot operate on 'SearchResults' variables because 'SearchResults' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator' [EmailCopier]csharp(CS1579)
forcpp(CS1579) instruction
(local variable) SearchResults? uids
'uids' is not null here.

Comment: You need to change the foreach loop like I showed in my answer above.

Comment: Tank you for helping it's work. But in my new serwer i have messeges in new time. It's posible to make copy mail/mail in original date?

Comment: Are you using the updated code that uses AppendRequest? That should fix it. If not, then the server is ignoring that.

Comment: 'MimeMessage' does not contain a definition of 'Keywords' and no available extension method 'Keywords' was found that takes a first argument of type 'MimeMessage' (is there a missing using directive or assembly reference?). [EmailCopier]csharp(CS1061)

Comment: MimeMessage' does not contain a definition of 'InternalDate' and no available extension method 'InternalDate' was found that takes a first argument of type 'MimeMessage' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). [EmailCopier]csharp(CS1061)

Comment: yes, but i don't now how to fixit

Comment: my modify

var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender Name", "sender@example.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "recipient@example.com"));
        message.Subject = "Example Subject";
        message.Headers.Add("Keywords", "important, personal, project");
        message.Headers.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));
        

        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = "Example message body."
        };

Comment: i've got:
Wystąpił wyjątek: CLR/MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException
Wystąpił wyjątek typu „MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException” w System.Private.CoreLib.dll, ale nie został obsłużony w kodzie użytkownika: 'The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.'
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.<ReadAheadAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.<ReadTokenAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapCommand.<StepAsync>d__84.MoveNext()

Comment: w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.<IterateAsync>d__190.MoveNext()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.<RunAsync>d__191.MoveNext()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.<AuthenticateAsync>d__105.MoveNext()

Comment: I'm sorry - Keywords and InternalDate should be on summary and not message.

Comment: thank you, i've got new extension

Wystąpił wyjątek: CLR/MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException
Wystąpił wyjątek typu „MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException” w System.Private.CoreLib.dll, ale nie został obsłużony w kodzie użytkownika: 'Syntax error in IMAP server greeting. Unexpected atom token: 220'

Comment: w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.AssertToken(ImapToken token, ImapTokenType type, String format, Object[] args)
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapEngine.<ConnectAsync>d__152.MoveNext()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient.<ConnectAsync>d__110.MoveNext()

Comment: I use this solution 
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/735

but don't work

Comment: You are trying to connect the ImapClient to the SMTP server/port. That obviously won't work.

Comment: I"m use 993 and don't work too

Comment: The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.

Comment: it is a problem to connect using this method

Wystąpił wyjątek: CLR/MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException
Wystąpił wyjątek typu „MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapProtocolException” w System.Private.CoreLib.dll, ale nie został obsłużony w kodzie użytkownika: 'The IMAP server has unexpectedly disconnected.'
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.<ReadAheadAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
   w System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   w MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapStream.<ReadTokenAsync>d__78.MoveNext()
   w System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()

Answer (score 0):

New code: **UPADTE2**

```
using MailKit.Net.Imap;
using MailKit.Security;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public string sourceServer;
    public int sourcePort;
    public string sourceUsername;
    public string sourcePassword;
    public string destinationServer;
    public int destinationPort;
    public string destinationUsername;
    public string destinationPassword;

    public Program(string sourceServer, int sourcePort, string sourceUsername, string sourcePassword,
                   string destinationServer, int destinationPort, string destinationUsername, string destinationPassword)
    {
        this.sourceServer = sourceServer;
        this.sourcePort = sourcePort;
        this.sourceUsername = sourceUsername;
        this.sourcePassword = sourcePassword;
        this.destinationServer = destinationServer;
        this.destinationPort = destinationPort;
        this.destinationUsername = destinationUsername;
        this.destinationPassword = destinationPassword;
    }

    public async Task CopyEmails()
    {
        using (var sourceClient = new ImapClient())
        using (var destinationClient = new ImapClient())
        {
            await sourceClient.ConnectAsync(sourceServer, sourcePort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await sourceClient.AuthenticateAsync(sourceUsername, sourcePassword);

            await destinationClient.ConnectAsync(destinationServer, destinationPort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await destinationClient.AuthenticateAsync(destinationUsername, destinationPassword);

            var sourceInbox = await sourceClient.GetFolderAsync("INBOX");
            var destinationInbox = await destinationClient.GetFolderAsync("INBOX");

            await CopyFolder(sourceInbox, destinationInbox);

            await sourceClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
            await destinationClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
        }
    }

    public async Task CopyFolder(IMailFolder sourceFolder, IMailFolder destinationFolder)
    {
         using (var sourceClient = new ImapClient())
        using (var destinationClient = new ImapClient())
        {
            await sourceClient.ConnectAsync(sourceServer, sourcePort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await sourceClient.AuthenticateAsync(sourceUsername, sourcePassword);

            await destinationClient.ConnectAsync(destinationServer, destinationPort, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            await destinationClient.AuthenticateAsync(destinationUsername, destinationPassword);

            var sourceInbox = await sourceClient.GetFolderAsync("INBOX");
            var destinationInbox = await destinationClient.GetFolderAsync("INBOX");

            await CopyFolder(sourceInbox, destinationInbox);

            await sourceClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
            await destinationClient.DisconnectAsync(true);
        
        await sourceFolder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
        await destinationFolder.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

        Console.WriteLine("Znaleziono folder INBOX na serwerze źródłowym.");
        Console.WriteLine("Znaleziono folder INBOX na serwerze docelowym.");

        var summaries = await sourceFolder.FetchAsync(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate | MessageSummaryItems.Flags);
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender Name", "sender@example.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Recipient Name", "recipient@example.com"));
        message.Subject = "Example Subject";
        message.Headers.Add("Keywords", "important, personal, project");
        message.Headers.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));
        

        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = "Example message body."
        };

        

        
        var internalDate = DateTime.Now;


        foreach (var summary in summaries)
        {
            var sourceMessage = await sourceInbox.GetMessageAsync(summary.UniqueId);

            var request = new AppendRequest(message);

            await destinationInbox.AppendAsync(request);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Skopiowano wiadomości z folderu INBOX.");
    }
    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceServer = "zmail.andoria.pl";
        int sourcePort = 993;
        string sourceUsername = "emial";
        string sourcePassword = "passwd";

        string destinationServer = "serwer2316905.home.pl";
        int destinationPort = 465;
        string destinationUsername = "emial";
        string destinationPassword = "passwd";

        var emailCopier = new Program(sourceServer, sourcePort, sourceUsername, sourcePassword,
                                      destinationServer, destinationPort, destinationUsername, destinationPassword);

        await emailCopier.CopyEmails();

        Console.WriteLine("Kopiowanie wiadomości zakończone.");
    }


}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?